# Does Oracle MapViewer support PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, maps, oracle-spatial

I use Oracle MapViewer to generate my mapping data and currently I'm using an Oracle database as my spatial back-end.  I would like to move my data over the PostGIS but I can't find any references if Oracle MapViewer actually supports PostGIS.

So my question is?  Is there out of the box support for PostGIS?  Would I have to write my own custom spatial data provider?

Comment: MapViewer is specifically built for Oracle Spatial. It not as good as one wishes. Geoserver was a better option in our workplace.

Comment: @Mapperz Hmmm... not good to hear.  Sadly we already have a lot invested in MapViewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for PostGIS in Oracle MapViewer, AFAIK.

MapViewer relies on Oracle Spatial, their [SDO_GEOMETRY](http://www.google.sk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objrelschema.htm&ei=ypb_UKbvNo6L4gTfkoCQBg&usg=AFQjCNGjWuT4iyNkajjqbNOz4MK-1rs16A&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bGE) type and Oracle SQL syntax dialect. MDSYS database schema is full of Oracle-specific GIS metadata, custom types etc. which cannot be easily ported to another database engine.
It uses JDBC to connect to database, which could theoretically allow it to connect to a non-Oracle server too, but it's not enough.

Comment: I know MapViewer has an alternative spatial provider interface but I think it's more intended for things like Shapefiles to supplement an Oracle installation.  I ended up going with GeoServer.